# Convert references to url-doi links

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle, awesome-cv

I am trying to update my CV, but the script that I was normally using isn't working anymore.

My CV is based on the awesome-CV template, and uses the awesome cls. However, one thing I wanted different than the standard class was to have the references as hyperlinks to the papers, and for that purpose I was using something like this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=darkblue,urlcolor=darkblue}
\geometry{left=1.4cm, top=.8cm, right=1.4cm, bottom=1.8cm, footskip=.5cm}
\fontdir[fonts/]

\newbibmacro{string+doiurl}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}
       {#1}
       {\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}}
    {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@driver#1{%
  \ifcsdef{blx@bbx@#1}
    {\usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\csuse{blx@bbx@#1}}}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@bbx@*}
       {\blx@warning{%
          No driver for entry type '#1'.\MessageBreak
          Using fallback driver}%
        \usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\csuse{blx@bbx@*}}}
       {\blx@error
          {No driver found}
          {I can't find a driver for the entry type
           '\abx@field@entrytype'\MessageBreak
           and there is no fallback driver either}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{test,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
    \nocite{test}
    \printbibliography[title={Journal Articles},
    heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

However, the problem is that this no longer works, and instead I get the error:

```
(pdf backend): \pdfextension endlink cannot be used in vertical mode
```

I am hoping there is a much smarter/standard way of doing what I want since the macro I am using is something I found online and do not really understand how worked (and now no longer seems to be working).

Comment: Have you tried deleting all of your `.aux`, `.toc` files and then rerunning your document? That error appears to be related to auxiliary files [(from latex.org)](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27385)

Comment: Yeah I have deleted all the files except the source files without success